# Change Migration Configuration Location

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, migration

Is there a way of changing the location of the Migrations/Configuration.cs file to another location without breaking EntityFramework migrations?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, migration functionality is not dependent on where the Configuration.cs file is. You may freely move it. When you call migration scripts it will still search for Configuration class in whole project. Remember only about properly setting MigrationsDirectory property within Configuration class - it points to folder where you have your migration classes defined.